# Hangman wordgame golf

Tags: code-golf, game, word-puzzle

Inspired by [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/gvnfk/i_submit_a_hangman_game_i_made_in_c_about_15/).

Write a program which plays [Hangman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_%28game%29).

- The program chooses a random word from a list of N words, where N > 2.
- The word list can be provided to the program in any way you choose.
- At each iteration

  - Print out the state of the game using underscores for letters not yet discovered:

  `H _ N _ _ _ N`

  - Print the number of remaining attempts

  `10`

  - Read a letter from stdin, and update the state of the game, subtracting an attempt if they guess an incorrect letter.

  `A` *(input)*

  `H A N _ _ A N`

  `10`

  - Repeat until all letters are guessed or attempts reaches 0
- Use any language
- Fewest number of characters wins.
- Drawing the gallows is not necessary, but will earn you upvotes and kudos.

Comment: Can I let each word in the list be the same number of characters?

Comment: Do the letters in the output have to be separated by spaces?

Comment: @Peter Of The Corn: you should assume that the word list is arbitrary

Comment: @Lowjacker: the spaces improve the legibility of consecutive underscores, otherwise it's hard to count how many letters they represent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ruby 1.9, <strike>134</strike> <strike>132</strike> <strike>120</strike> <strike>117</strike> <strike>108</strike> 107

Word list provided in ARGV. The words and the entered letters must match in case.

```
r=w=$*.sample
t=10
loop{puts [*w.tr(r,?_).chars]*' ',t
t>0&&r>''?w[l=STDIN.gets[0]]?r=r.tr(l,''):t-=1:exit}
```

Answer (score 8):

Python 3.

```
from random,sys import *
w=choice(*argv)
L=set(w)
a=10
while L and a:
 print(" ".join("_"if x in L else x for x in w),a)
 try:L-=set(input()[0])
 except:a-=1
```

I prefer this one though: longer but nicer.

```
import random
w=random.choice(list(open("/usr/dict/words")))[:-1]
L=set(w)
a=10
while L and a:
 print(" ".join("_"if x in L else x for x in w),a)
 try:L.remove(input()[0])
 except:a-=1
print w
```

Comment: If I didn't have to print `a` as well, I could use the `*` twice: `print(*("_"if x in L else x for x in w))`

Answer (score 8):

Darn, I thought it said "fewest number of lines wins." I'm not going to win any fewest-character contests here, but this Common Lisp program is only one line.

```
(let ((words (list "that" "help" "rent" "chair" "octopus" "monitor" "manual" "speakers" "onomatopoeia" "regardless" "irresponsible" "cornerstone"))) (let ((word (nth (random (length words)) words))) (format t "~a~%" (funcall (defun play (word current remaining-attempts) (progn (if (not (find #\_ current)) (return-from play "You win!")) (if (equalp remaining-attempts 0) (return-from play "You lose!")) (format t "~a~%~d~%" current remaining-attempts) (let ((guess (char (read-line) 0)) (index 0) (found nil)) (loop for letter across word do (if (equalp guess letter) (progn (setf (char current index) letter) (setf found t))) (setf   index (+ index 1))) (if found (play word current remaining-attempts) (play word current (- remaining-attempts 1)))))) word (map 'string #'(lambda (c) #\_) word) 10))))
```

Comment: I'm upvoting you because I'm pretty sure you're being intentionally humorous :-)

Answer (score 4):

c++ (-headers)

```
struct h{h(char a):b(a){}char operator()(char c,char d){return d!='_'?d:c==b?c:'_';}char b;};

int main(int a,char**b){
srand(time(0));string c=*(b+rand()%(a-1)+1),d(c.size(),'_'),e;
char f=10,g;
while(f){
cout<<"> ";cin>>g;e=d;
transform(c.begin(),c.end(),d.begin(),d.begin(),h(g));if(e==d)--f;
cout<<d<<endl<<(int)f<<endl;if(d==c)break;
}return 0;}
```

cat /usr/dict/words | xargs hangman

Comment: The "> " prompt for input is not necessary for the solution, I just added it in the question to indicate that it was input, as many languages provide a prompt such as this.

Comment: @drspod You should edit the question to reflect that, then.

Comment: edited to clarify

Answer (score 2):

### Python

```
import random

DEFAULT_ATTEMPTS = 10

def print_word(word, uncovered):
    for c in word:
        if c not in uncovered:
            c = '_'
        print c,
    print ''

def get_letter():
    letter = None
    while letter is None:
        letter = raw_input('> ')
        if len(letter) != 1:
            print 'Letters must be 1 character.  Try again.'
            letter = None
    return letter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) != 2: sys.exit(1)
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        words = [word.strip() for word in f.readlines() if word.strip()]

    word = random.choice(words)
    uncovered = set([' '])
    attempts = DEFAULT_ATTEMPTS

    while attempts > 0 and any(letter not in uncovered for letter in word):
        print_word(word, uncovered)
        print attempts

        letter = get_letter()
        if letter in uncovered:
            print 'You have already tried that letter.'
        elif letter in word:
            print 'You got it!'
        else:
            print 'Wrong!'
            attempts -= 1

        uncovered.add(letter)

    if attempts == 0:
        print 'You lose!',
    else:
        print 'You win!'
    print 'The phrase was "%s".' % word
```

I didn't really try for the fewest characters, just wanted to make it as small as possible without sacrificing anything.

Comment: @user: You may be interested in [George Edison's wonderful user script for this site](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170/code-golf-userscript-to-help-in-navigating-the-site-v0-37-now-available) which puts your code (as copied here by badp) at 1225 characters.

Comment: I think that's cause I was using tabs and they were converted to spaces here.  wc says it's 1034 with tabs.

Comment: @user: Yes. A [well known difficulty](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42/tab-characters-in-code-golf-answers/275#275) with python submissions.

Answer (score 2):

Perl, 112 char.  I feel like I can do better - perhaps I'll try again later

```
$_=$ARGV[rand@ARGV];$a=10;while($a&&/[a-z]/){print map/[A-Z]/?$_:'_',split'';$x=<STDIN>;chop$x;s/$x/$x/ig||$a--}
```

Words are given on the command line, letters typed upper case

Comment: Down to 107

`$_=$ARGV[rand@ARGV];$a=10;while($a&&/[a-z]/){$y=$_;$y=~y/a-z/_/;print$y;$x=<STDIN>;chop$x;s/$x/$x/ig||$a--}`

Comment: You could just edit your original answer.

Comment: This doesn't display the number of remaining attempts.

Answer (score 2):

**Clojure**

This is 400 bytes gzipped, which is still quite a lot, probably because of how Clojure handles mutable state.

```
(def m ["will" "work" "for" "food"])
(def w (nth m (rand-int (count m))))
(def *s* (atom (replicate (count w) "_")))
(def *a* (atom 10))

(defn g [s a]
  (str (apply str (interpose " " s)) "\n" a))

(loop [n (read-line)]
  (if (some (set n) w)
    (swap! *s* (fn [s]
                 (map 
                   (fn [i]
                     (if (= n (str (nth w i)))
                       n
                       (nth s i)))
                   (range 0 (count s)))))
    (swap! *a* dec))

  (println (g (deref *s*) (deref *a*))) 

  (if (and (< 0 (deref *a*)) (some #{"_"} (deref *s*)))
    (recur (read-line))))
```

Answer (score 2):

C# 370

```
using System;namespace h{class P{static void Main(string[]a){int c=10,d,l;char y=' ';string w=a[new Random().Next(a.Length)];l=w.Length;char[]x=new char[l];for(d=-1;++d<l;x[d]='-');while(c>0){for(d=-1;++d<l;x[d]=(y==w[d]||x[d]!='-')?w[d]:x[d]);Console.WriteLine(new string(x)+" "+c);if(w==new string(x))return;y=Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;if(!w.Contains(y+""))c--;}}}
```

wordlist as argument

Answer (score 1):

## VB.NET

<s>I haven't tried shrinking it yet, but:</s>
<s>First shrinking:</s>
Second shrinking (3759 characters):

```
Module Hangman
    Sub Main()
        Dim m As Int32, w = "banana|apple|pear|dog|cat|orange|monkey|programming|hangman".Split("|")(New Random().Next(9)), g = "", e = "", x, c As Char, f As Boolean, r = Sub(z) Console.Write(z), p = Sub(y, h) Console.SetCursorPosition(y, h), a = Sub() Console.Clear(), q = Function() Console.ReadKey(1), d = Sub()
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          r("       +--------+S       |        |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S                |S   ---------------------".Replace("S", vbCrLf))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          p(0, 2)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          r(String.Join(vbCrLf, "    /------\S    | O   O|S    \  ... /S     ------ S        |   S        |   S        |   S        |   S -------+-------S        |   S        |   S        |   S       / \  S      /   \  S     /     \  S    /       \  ".Split("S").Take(m * 4)))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      End Sub
        Console.CursorVisible = 0
        Do
            a()
            d()
            p(30, 10)
            f = 0
            For Each x In w
                If g.Contains(x) Then
                    r(x)
                Else
                    r(" ")
                    f = 1
                End If
                Console.CursorTop += 1
                Console.CursorLeft -= 1
                r("_")
                Console.CursorTop -= 1
                r(" ")
            Next
            If Not f Then
                a()
                d()
                p(30, 10)
                r("You win! Press any key to close.")
                q()
                End
            End If
            p(30, 13)
            r(e)
            Do
                c = q().KeyChar
            Loop Until Char.IsLetter(c)
            If g.Contains(c) Then
                e = "You have already guessed that letter."
            Else
                g &= c
                If w.Contains(c) Then
                    e = "There is a" & If("aehilmnorsx".Contains(c), "n", "") & " """ & c & """ in the word."
                Else
                    e = "There is no """ & c & """ in the word. Try again."
                    m += 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop Until m = 4
        a()
        d()
        p(30, 10)
        r("You lose! Press any key to close.")
        q()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Is all the indentation really required?

Comment: it makes it easier to read, doesn't it?

Comment: As in blocks? No, it's not required, but I don't count it as characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 125 bytes

```powershell
$w=$h=$args|random|% t*y
for($n=10){$w-replace"[ $h]",'_'-join' ';$n
if(!$h+!$n){break}$n-=($c=Read-Host)-notin$h
$h=$h-ne$c}
```

Less golfed test script:

```powershell
$f = {

$word=$hidden=$args|random|% toCharArray    # let $word and $hidden are a random word chars
#$word                                      # uncomment this to cheating
for($n=10){                                 # forever for with init section
    $word-replace"[ $hidden]",'_'-join' '   # display the word with hidden letters
    $n                                      # display $n
    if(!$hidden+!$n){break}                 # break loop if hidden array is empty or n equal to 0
    $n-=($c=Read-Host)-notin$hidden         # input $c from user, decrease $n if $c does not in $hidden array
    $hidden=$hidden-ne$c                    # recreate $hidden array with removed $c
}

}

$words = gc .\wordlist.txt
&$f $words
```

Output example when the guessing player has *lost*:

```powershell
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
10
i
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
9
e
_ _ e _ _ _ _ e
9
o
o _ e _ _ o _ e
9
a
o _ e _ _ o _ e
8
q
o _ e _ _ o _ e
7
q
o _ e _ _ o _ e
6
q
o _ e _ _ o _ e
5
q
o _ e _ _ o _ e
4
q
o _ e _ _ o _ e
3
q
o _ e _ _ o _ e
2
q
o _ e _ _ o _ e
1
q
o _ e _ _ o _ e
0
```

Output example when the guessing player has *win*:

```powershell
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
10
e
_ _ _ _ e _ _ _ _ _
10
o
_ o _ _ e _ _ _ _ _
10
i
_ o _ _ e _ _ i _ _
10
a
_ o _ _ e _ _ i a _
10
l
_ o _ _ e _ _ i a l
10
c
c o _ _ e _ c i a l
10
m
c o m m e _ c i a l
10
t
c o m m e _ c i a l
9
r
c o m m e r c i a l
9
```