# Ascii art hangman

Tags: code-golf

Although there was  a [hangman competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/hangman-wordgame-golf) before, I don't feel it was beautiful enough. The challenge is to implement a clone of http://inventwithpython.com/chapter9.html but as in the previous competition you can input the list of words in any way you want.  The main difference is therefore just that you have to draw the gallows in ascii as the game goes on.

Comment: [Hangman wordgame golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/hangman-wordgame-golf) already allows for drawing a gallows. That aside, a question should be reasonably self-contained.

Comment: The ASCII Gallows Club implemented a better version of hangman than that. It isn't based on it, but may I submit it anyway? We have many improvements over that game, and our gallows look excellent.

Comment: @user2509848 Of course!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

You will need to put the lists in a folder named wordlists, which is placed in the same folder as the source.  You can download the full .zip here: https://github.com/OddLlama/ascii-gallows-club.

This program allows 7 guesses until completion, and allows guessing the full word in one blow, if you think you know it.  It has a debug mode, where you enter 'debug' instead of the number of players, and does not allow you to enter a guess more than once.  It also allows 2-player mode, where one player enters the word, and a second player guesses it.  In this mode, the entered word does not display while being typed.  Other features are score-keeping and displaying special characters (although the lists haven't been updated to represent that):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random # for choosing a word
import os # for finding files in wordlists directory
import textwrap # for ASCII art dedentation
import time # for sleeping at the end
import getpass # for 2 player

# grab all the filenames
categories = [f.split('.')[0] for f in os.listdir('wordlists')]

debug_mode = False
def debug(s):
  if debug_mode: print('[DEBUG] ' + s)

def print_ASCII(ascii_str):
  "Print ASCII art."
  print(textwrap.dedent(ascii_str))

def header():
  "Print the header."
  print_ASCII("""
    /=======================\\
    | Welcome to Hangman!!! |
    \\=======================/
  """)

def choose_category():
  "Request the user to input a category."
  for i, cat in enumerate(categories):  # print the categories & numbers
    print('%i. %s' % (i, cat))
  choice = input('Please enter a category name or number: ').lower()
  if choice.isdigit() and 0 <= int(choice) < len(categories):
    choice = categories[int(choice)]
  for i, cat in enumerate(categories):
    if choice == str(i): choice = cat
  while choice not in categories:  # loop until user enters a valid category
    choice = input('Invalid category. Try again: ')
    if choice.isdigit() and 0 <= int(choice) < len(categories):
      choice = categories[int(choice)]
  return choice

def get_word(category):
  "Retrieve a random word from a category."
  with open('wordlists/%s.txt' % category) as f: # use `with` for automatic file closure
  words = f.readlines()
  return random.choice(words).rstrip('\n').strip().lower()

def get_guess(guessed):
  "Get the user to guess a letter."
  guess = input('Guess: ').lower()
  while guess in guessed:
    guess = input('You already guessed that. Try again: ').lower()
  return guess

# draw gallows
def draw_board(bad_guesses, word):

  length = len(bad_guesses)

  # this is also always drawn
  print_ASCII("""
    ______________
    | /          |
    |/           |
    |{0}          {2}{1}{3}
    |            {4}
    |            {5}
    |           {6} {7}
    |
    |
    | {8}
    |________________|""".format('  ' if length == 1 else '', 'O' if length > 0 else '', '__' if len(bad_guesses) > 1 else '',
                                 '__' if len(bad_guesses) > 2 else '', '|' if length > 3 else '', '|' if length > 4 else '',
                                 '/' if length > 5 else '', '\\' if length > 6 else '',
                                 ' '.join(map(lambda s: '[%s]' % s, bad_guesses))).strip('\n'))

def hangman(word):  # main function
  """
  Plays hangman!
  Returns True if the user won, False otherwise.
  """

  debug('The word is %s' % word)

  # the lines showing the word so far
  guess = ['_' if char.isalnum() else char for char in word]

  # already guessed and wrong guesses
  guessed = []
  bad_guesses = []
  while len(bad_guesses) < 7: # main loop
    # print letters so far
    print(' '.join(guess))

    # request input
    letter = get_guess(guessed)
    guessed.append(letter)

    # check if letter is correct or not
    if letter in word or letter == word:
      # update chars guessed so far
      guess = [letter if char == letter else guess_char for char, guess_char in zip(word, guess)]
      if letter == word: guess = list(word)

      # did they win?
      if ''.join(guess) == word:
          print('Congratulations, you guessed the word: %s!' % word)
          return True
    else:
      bad_guesses.append(letter)
      print('%s is not in the word.' % letter)

    # add a little separation
    print()
    draw_board(bad_guesses, word)

  # if program reaches here, user failed
  print('You couldn\'t guess the word. It was %s.' % word)
  return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
  header()
  players = input('How many players? 1 for playing against computer, 2 for playing against another human: ')
  while players not in ['1', '2', 'debug']:
    players = input('Invalid input. Please try again: ')

  # debug mode stuff
  if players == 'debug':
    debug_mode = True
    debug('Debug mode has been turned on.')
  while players not in ['1', '2']:
    players = input('Number of players: ')

  print() # spacing

  if players == '1':
    wins, losses = 0, 0
    if hangman(get_word(choose_category())): wins += 1
    else: losses += 1
    while True:
      print('You have won %i time%s and lost %i time%s.' % (wins, '' if wins == 1 else 's', losses, '' if losses == 1 else 's'))
      again = input('Play again? (y/n): ').lower() == 'y'
      print() # separation
      if again:
          if hangman(get_word(choose_category())): wins += 1
          else: losses += 1
      else:
          break
  else:
    while True:
      word = getpass.getpass('Word maker: enter your word (the input will not be shown): ')
      hangman(word)
      again = input('Play again? (y/n): ').lower() == 'y'
      print() # separation
      if not again: break

print('Goodbye!')
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Me, this user, PhiNotPi, and Volatility all worked on this one together :D

Comment: Yes. Sorry about forgetting the credits, @DoorknobofSnow.  I guess I should have know better than to plagiarize.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Maybe we should start a group account for answering these questions?